# Custom filter not working with solr

Tags: java, solr, filter, lucene

I have created a custom filter factory for solr 4.2. It is working good. But when I am trying to upgarde solr-4.2 to 4.7 version, it is reporting errors:

> Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.ExtendedNameFilterFactory'

Here's the java code for the factory:

```
package org.apache.lucene.analysis;

import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.AbstractAnalysisFactory;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.MultiTermAwareComponent;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.TokenFilterFactory;

public class ExtendedNameFilterFactory extends TokenFilterFactory
  implements MultiTermAwareComponent
{
  int extendedWordCount;

  public void init(Map<String, String> args)
  {
    super.init(args);
    assureMatchVersion();
    this.extendedWordCount = getInt("extendedWordCount", -1);
  }

  public ExtendedNameFilter create(TokenStream input) {
    return new ExtendedNameFilter(this.luceneMatchVersion, input, this.extendedWordCount);
  }

  public AbstractAnalysisFactory getMultiTermComponent()
  {
    return this;
  }
}
```

And for the Filter:

```
package org.apache.lucene.analysis;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.CharTermAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.OffsetAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.tokenattributes.PositionIncrementAttribute;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.util.CharacterUtils;
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version;

public final class ExtendedNameFilter extends TokenFilter
{
  private final CharTermAttribute termAtt = (CharTermAttribute)addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);
  private PositionIncrementAttribute posIncAttr;
  private OffsetAttribute setOffsetAttr;
  private final int extendedWordCount;
  LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList();
  ArrayList<Integer> startOffsetList = new ArrayList();
  int endOffset = 0;
  int count = 0;

  public ExtendedNameFilter(Version matchVersion, TokenStream in, int extendedWordCount)
  {
    super(in);
    CharacterUtils.getInstance(matchVersion);
    this.extendedWordCount = extendedWordCount;
    this.posIncAttr = ((PositionIncrementAttribute)addAttribute(PositionIncrementAttribute.class));
    this.setOffsetAttr = ((OffsetAttribute)addAttribute(OffsetAttribute.class));
  }

  public final boolean incrementToken()
    throws IOException
  {
    int len = 0;

    while (this.input.incrementToken()) {
      this.list.add(this.termAtt.toString());
      this.startOffsetList.add(Integer.valueOf(this.setOffsetAttr.startOffset()));
      this.endOffset = this.setOffsetAttr.endOffset();
    }

    Iterator iterator = this.list.iterator();
    len = this.list.size();

    if ((len > 0) && (this.extendedWordCount < 0)) {
      this.termAtt.setEmpty();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        this.termAtt.append((CharSequence)iterator.next());
      }
      this.list.removeFirst();

      this.posIncAttr.setPositionIncrement(10);
      this.setOffsetAttr.setOffset(((Integer)this.startOffsetList.get(this.count)).intValue(), this.endOffset);
      this.count += 1;
      return true;
    }
    if ((len > 0) && (this.count < this.extendedWordCount)) {
      this.termAtt.setEmpty();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        this.termAtt.append((CharSequence)iterator.next());
      }
      this.list.removeFirst();

      this.posIncAttr.setPositionIncrement(10);
      this.setOffsetAttr.setOffset(((Integer)this.startOffsetList.get(this.count)).intValue(), this.endOffset);
      this.count += 1;
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
}
```

It was working good with solr 4.2. Can anybody tell me the changes that I need to make for running it in solr 4.7.1?

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractAnalysisFactory` no longer uses an init method for passing in args.  Override the [constructor](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/AbstractAnalysisFactory.html#AbstractAnalysisFactory%28java.util.Map%29) instead.